# How to set Eclipse and PyDev for QGIS when ArcGIS is installed?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, qgis-2

I have got a lot problems with the configuration of Eclipse with PyDev in order to develop QGIS plugins. The situation is very weird and frustrating. I can import qgis module using Pyscripter without any problems but in the case of Eclipse I have already spend a few hours to find out solution.  I check a lot of tutorials from the Internet but I have not get answer  to my question yet. This is not a duplicate question because I have checked all solutions form other questions. In my case I have got ArcGIS 10.2 and QGIS 2.2 installed on my machine.

I use the script below to run PyScripter

```
@echo off
call "%~dp0\o4w_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\env.bat
@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set PYTHONPATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python
Set PATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGISHOME=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\
Start c:\PROGRA~2\PyScripter\pyscripter.exe --python27 --pythondllpath=C:\OSGeo4W\bin
```

In that case I can import qgis or qgis.core without any  problems.

When I check paths using :

```
import sys
for item in sys.path:
    print item
```

I get this result:

```
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python
C:\OSGeo4W\bin\python27.zip
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
```

As the results I get ready working with QGIS Pyscripter but using this software I can not debug my plugin.

In the case of Eclipse I use this bat file

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=c:\OSGeo4W
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\env.bat
@echo off
SET GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\gdalplugins
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis
"C:\Progra~2\eclipse\eclipse.exe"
```

When I use piece of code mentioned above to check paths I get:

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-2.2-py2.7.egg
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\sphinx-1.2.1-py2.7.egg
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\docutils-0.11-py2.7.egg
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\pygments-1.6-py2.7.egg
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.18-py2.7.egg
c:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python
c:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages
c:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\DLLs
c:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib
c:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\OSGeo4W\bin
c:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27
c:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
c:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
c:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
c:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
c:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg
c:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\OSGeo4W\bin\python27.zip
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\DLLs
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\lib-tk
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts
```

Of course I set Forced Builtins for qgis and PyQt4 but still It does not work.

When I try to run import qgis I get this error 
and I get error

```
from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
ImportError: DLL load failed The specified module could not be found.
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: This is Rajesh I whave a doubt form QGIS 2.2 version in my system can't enable to install in new plugins, It will showing red color . Is there any option form in my system please tel me as soon as possible.
![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LCsVq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to use the batch file to set the eclipse before and it did not work. Probably I have received the same error message as you.

Later, I tried to set the path & pythonhome directly in the eclipse interpreter environment setting. And it works for me.

PATH:
`C:\OSGeo4W\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin`

PYTHONPATH:
`C:\OSGeo4W\apps\python27`

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure a new interpreter. The python selected for the interpreter should be the OSGeo4w Python, not the system Python. For any given Pydev project you pick which interpreter to use. That way ArcPy and OSGeo Python are never together in the path.

Just update, the paths and versions to match.
http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2010-February/009182.html

Follow up info.
http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/ide_debugging.html